# I'm trying to add graphics to the application. I'm getting an error when trying to add the MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, kotlin, graph, dependencies

```
 implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
```

Build Gradle.app section.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

    def nav_version = "2.3.5"
    classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version")



    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {

        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Project section.

There was no allprojects section in my file. That's why I added this place myself. But those defined in allprojects

```
Google()
mavenCentral()
 maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
```

It has to be in shape. When I try to introduce google() and mavenCentral, it gives error already defined in buildScript. When I try to define only `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` without defining google() and mavenCentral; **Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'maven' was added by build file 'build.gradle'.**  I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you can open `settings.gradle` and change

```
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
```

to

```
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
```

I usually set my `allprojects` to the following when using `MPAndroidChart`, and it works as long as `repositoriesMode` is set to `PREFER_SETTINGS`.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

You can also just add `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` to the `repositories` section in that same `settings.gradle` file instead too.